# Eclipse for Mac will not start in full screen mode

Tags: eclipse, macos

Because programmers SE says:

> coding tools, such as compilers, debuggers, and IDEs (ask on Stack Overflow instead)

So this may be a bit mundane, but this is part of my work flow. I like to keep Eclipse in full screen, so I can switch back and forth to browser / remote desktop with ctrl+arrow. The problem is Eclipse (this is ADT, but I don't think it matters?) always starts in non-full screen mode, even if I left it on full screen before I close it

Is there a way to get Eclipse to always start in full screen mode? Or at least remember what state it was in before whenever it starts?

Google search keywords I've tried:

1. "Eclipse for Mac fullscreen mode" only yields articles about full screen support on Mac OS X Lion (and not about starting it in full screen)
2. "ADT Mac full screen mode" yields articles about switching Android Emulator to landscape

Additionally I tried to look for "eclipse mac full screen" here on SO and I don't find anything relevant

I'm using ADT 22.6 on Mac OS X Mavericks

Comment: As far as I can see from the API calls in the source Eclipse does not support this.

Comment: Other applications such as Opera is capable of this. Is this the limitation of how Eclipse was built or a limitation in how Eclipse works?

Comment: There are APIs available in Eclipse (SWT) to do this but it just has not been coded in the Eclipse RCP.

Comment: Is that so? Well I suppose I'll just have to wait until it's updated. Can you please put it up as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the Eclipse source there does not seem to be any support for this currently.

The SWT `Shell.setFullScreen(true)` call does switch the app in to Mac full screen mode but Eclipse only uses it when the full screen menu item is used.